# Procedural semantics of swi-Prolog: failure to understand the resulting substitution

Tags: prolog, semantics, substitution

I fail to understand swi-prolog's behavior when the database

**on(a,b).**

is queried with

**:- on(A,B),on(C,D).**

To my best understanding, what is supposed to happen is the following: first, the leftmost goal in the query is matched against the database. This succeeds immediately, leading to the removal of said goal from the query as well as to the substitution

**[A=a,B=b]**

Next, this substitution is applied to the remaining goal, which does nothing, since neither A nor B appear in the second goal. Now, the remaining goal is matched against the database, which again succeeds. Now we are done, and we should be left with the substitution

**[A=a,B=b,C=a,D=b]**

And this should be the only substitution the interpreter is able to come up with, provided my understanding of prologs procedural semantics is correct. Unfortunately, swi-prolog thinks otherwise. Instead it comes up with the substitution

**[A=C,B=D,C=a,D=b]**

If you are very generous, you could say that "both answers mean the same", but I am never generous when it comes to understanding what a program does, and I ran into this in a context where it actually matters. So I would be most appreciative if someone could help me to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Something close to the output you want but using the usual Prolog pair representation:

```
bindings(Query, Bindings) :-
    term_variables(Query, Variables),
    copy_term(Query, Copy),
    term_variables(Copy, VariablesCopy),
    call(Copy),
    pairs_keys_values(Bindings, Variables, VariablesCopy).
```

Sample call:

```
?- bindings((on(A,B),on(C,D)), Bindings).
Bindings = [A-a, B-b, C-a, D-b].
```

The only non-standard predicate is `pairs_keys_values/3` but this is available in several libraries. Above I used `library(pairs)` from SWI-Prolog. Logtalk (which you can run with most Prolog systems) provides a [`pairs`](https://logtalk.org/library/pairs_0.html) library object with a [`keys_values/3`](https://logtalk.org/library/pairs_0.html#keys-values-3) predicate with the same semantics and argument order.

Comment: Thank you, that certainly works. So the practical side of my question is resolved. However, I still fail to understand what exactly swi-prolog does to infer A=C, B=D. Obviously, my idea of prologs procedural semantics does not precisely capture what the warren abstact machine (the engine under the hood of swi-prolog) is doing.

Answer (score 1):

But the two substitutions *are* the same.

We can only know a thing by its interactions; for *any* valid implementation of `substitute( Term, Substitution, Substituted_term )` no difference can be observed with either of the two forms you show.

It is thus purely a matter of representation. Any representation can be chosen as long as the observable results remain the same.

Comment: There is no doubt that you  are right as far as the  meaning of the result is concerned. However, how does the prolog interpreter know that A=C and B=D. Provided that the path of computation is as described in my opening question, it should not.

Comment: in that case yours is more of a *language-implementation* question. perhaps it should be tagged as such, so this is clear.

Comment: Maybe SWI does some "condensing" step each time it adds new binding into the current substitution; or even just when reporting it to the top-level...

Comment: @Nestor We will never know. The toplevel could have the stance that it just prints every term once (it already aggressivel shortens lists on printout, grrr) and when it encounters another variable referencing that term, it will just print variable equality expression instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the result is even valid for:

```
on(a,b).
on2(a,b).

?- on(A,B),on2(C,D).
A = C, C = a,
B = D, D = b.
```

In any case it would be nicer of Prolog to write

```
A = C = a,
B = D = b.
```

Here is a diagram from earlier I adapted. I have no idea whether things are implemented like that, Maybe NULL pointers are used when the variable is "fresh"? It's not important.

[image: Variables and their bindings]

Comment: I sometimes think of logvars as "named pointers" of sorts. *set-once* (i.e. "single-assignment") of course (sans backtracking). when a term's inner free logvar is set further down the road, the top binding for that term remains as is. (that's talking procedurally). for `A=p(X), X=z`, either `{A-->p(X)}` turns into `{A-->p(X); X-->z}` or `{A--> place1:value=p( place2:value=X ) ; X--> NIL}` turns into `{A--> place1:value=p( place2:value=z ) ; X--> place2}` (i.e. without sharing or with it). something like that maybe. I haven't actually ever implemented a Prolog of my own.

Comment: @WillNess Sometimes I wonder how it is even possible to program in Prolog, because one never considers all the implications of what's going on in there, and one still can emit code regardless. There is a PhD in Cognitive Science in there for sure.

Comment: the implications are the same, semantically; the only possible difference is  operational (i.e. same value, different time/space to get there). this is much more pronounced in Haskell btw. and 2nd btw, my "dream" is to never bother myself with operational considerations -- that's what compilers are supposed to be there for. :) maybe some day. :)